# getResultList() in init-method giving error "session is closed"

Tags: java, spring, jpa, applicationcontext

I am trying to load some data from DB in the init method of my service class but when I call the "getResultList()" method then it throws an Exception "Session is closed".

my applicationContext.xml

```
<bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />    
<bean id="testService" class="com.impl.TestServiceImpl" init-method="init" />
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
</bean>
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
```

my service class:

```
public Class TestServiceImpl implements TestService {
private EntityManager entityManager;

@PersistenceContext
public void setEntityManager(EntityManager entityManager) {
   this.entityManager = entityManager;
}   

public void init() {
    Query query = entityManager.createQuery("from myTable");
    query.getResultList();  // this causes error...
}
}
```

This is the error message:

```
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class 
org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 
'testService' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: 
Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.SessionException: Session is 
closed!
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.SessionException: 
Session is closed!
at 
org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.throwPersistenceException(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:630)
```

So what I am doing wrong here? How can I solve this issue? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all your `TestServiceImpl` is not annotated with `@Transactional`, but even if it was, it wouldn't work, see: [Transactional init-method](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?21329-Transactional-init-method) and [SPR-2740](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-2740) - which explains this is by design.

What you can do is to use `init()` method only to call some other bean's business method, which is marked `@Transactional`.

```
private TestDao testDao;

public void init() {
  testDao.findAll();
}
```

And in `TestDao` bean:

```
private EntityManager entityManager;

@Transactional
public findAll() {
  Query query = entityManager.createQuery("from myTable");
  return query.getResultList();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, calling some other bean's business method worked for, by the way I already had @Transactional on the service class(forget to put it in the question) but as you mentioned even if it was there it wouldn't have worked.